# How to access to appsettings from service class in .net core 7 application using minimal api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, inversion-of-control, appsettings, minimal-apis

I'm working on a .net core 7 application. I have to implement a minimal api using a service class.
In this service class, i've to access to appsettings.
In the **program.cs** file, i have the following lines :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Local.json", true);
builder.Configuration["groupParameterOne:ParameterA"];
```

I need to access to appsettings from a service class but i don't know how to inject the builder in my service class.

I can implement a static class to set and access my settings but i don't think it's the right way to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up authentication endpoints class in minimal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424984/setting-up-authentication-endpoints-class-in-minimal-api)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using .net Maui and .net 7 and this is how I access appsettings in a Singleton.

In Program add to the builder`.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false);`
To the builder services add a singleton `builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppSettingsReader>();`

In the singleton service I want to be able to access the config settings in I create a private IConfiguration field called _configuration and then create a constructor and pass in IConfiguration setting the private field equal to config, so my constructor looks like this.

`public TheSingletonService(IConfiguration config)  { _configuration = config; }`

Now I have access to config values stored in appsettings.  You need to make sure that when adding the JSONFile you make sure to specify the file is required by passing in a value of false to the optional param.