# How can I Inject Minimal Endpoint class in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, minimal-apis

I am using ASP.NET Core 7 for a project in which I am using Minimal endpoints. In the default minimal endpoint project, the endpoints are directly mapped in the `program.cs` class like this:

```
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
});
```

I want to do it in a structured way to maintain when the project scope increases. If I have a `Product` endpoint I want a separate class that only concerns `Product` endpoints same as the `Order` endpoints class.

I have tried the below way but when I am injecting a service I am getting an argument error because the `Product` and `Order` class constructor require objects of their respective repositories.

Here is my code:

```
public class ProductEndpoint : IEndpoint
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductEndpoint(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public void MyRoutes(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapPost("/product/create", CreateProduct);
    }

    private async Task CreateProduct(HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(await _productRepository.CreateProduct());
    }
}
```

And in the `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

var endpoints = new List<IEndpoint>
{
    //There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'productRepository' of 'MyProject.ProductEndpoint(IProductRepository)'
    new ProductEndpoint()
};

foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
{
    endpoint.MapRoutes(app);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sens ... then you should use controllers ...

Comment: for minimal API you would `CreateProduct` like `static Task<IResult> CreateProduct(IProductRepository productRepository) => Results.Json(await productRepository.CreateProduct());` and thats it

Comment: if you want DI services in minimal APIs you need to include them as parameters:  `app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (IProductRepository repository) => {...});`

Comment: @Selvin oh right, your first comment is 100% valid. OP is trying to achieve exact same encapsulation that controllers already give.

Comment: You don't inject minimal APIs. The concept makes no sense because no other application component is going to *use* them. The code you posted is actually more than what you'd use for a controller. If you want to *define* endpoints in other methods or classes, you can, as long as you still use `MapGet`, MapPut, etc. The *easy* way to do this is to write the code you want in Program.cs, select it and then use the `Extract method` refactoring. The generated method should pass `app` as an `IEndpointBuilder`. MapGet etc are extension methods on that interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this was possible (and you can make it work with some custom scopes and etc.) it still has a major issue - all the `ProductEndpoint` injected dependencies will become ["captive" ones](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) i.e. all the request will be handled by the same instance of `IProductRepository` which is usually is not what you want (especially if you are using some ORM like EF Core). Just move dependencies on the handler level and make the handler `static`:

```
public class ProductEndpoint : IEndpoint
{
    public void MyRoutes(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapPost("/product/create", CreateProduct);
    }

    private static async Task<CreateProductResponse> CreateProduct(HttpContext context, IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        return await productRepository.CreateProduct(); 
    }
}
```

Notes:

- No need to "manually" handle the `HttpContext` reading and writing, use the [binding capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) provided by the framework and it's ability to handle results
- Personally I would not bother with instances and interface but just used static classes with extension methods - see [Minimal API in .NET 6 using multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70139392/2501279)
- Consider using [route groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-groups)
- As Selvin correctly suggests better name would be `Register` not `MyRoutes`.
- Also: [What is the correct lifetime for classes used to organize Minimal Api endpoints and should I resolve them in CreateScope()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76068990/2501279) can provide some useful info.

Comment: `IEndpoint` is useless here  unless it is defined as `interface IEndpoint
{
        /*I would call it Register*/
 static abstract void MyRoutes(WebApplication app);
}` ... so you would rember to implement static methods and then call `ProductEndpoint.Register(app);` in main file **(of course all methods in `ProductEndpoint` should be static then)**

Comment: @Selvin `ProductEndpoint` is not a static class and `MyRoutes` is not a static method (agree n the `Register` renaming). TBH defining static interface here would kind of pointless unless the interface search would be done with reflection. Updated the handler method to be `static`.

Comment: Having non static defeats using minimal API as we have Controllers ...

Comment: question: *will become "captive" ones* does it applies to static ? like `app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (IProductRepository repository) => {...})` / `static ... Create((IProductRepository repository) => ...;` `app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", Create)`

Comment: @Selvin updated the comment and the answer - `CreateProduct` should better be static. _"Having non static defeats using minimal API as we have Controllers"_ - TBH disagree with this statement, there are some other points of using minimal apis over MVC/Controllers.

Comment: @Selvin _"does it applies to static"_ - no, it applies to the attempt made by OP and deps resolved in `ProductEndpoint` ctor .