# Routing file in ASP.NET Core 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm in the process of evolving my knowledge and skill in ASP.NET Core so as i was working with laravel we have a file that include and summarize all the route of all the controller in the project so i was wondering if i could do the same in asp.net core because i don't want to include all the mapping of controllers in program.cs

```
<?php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function ()
{
    Route::get('ajout', ['as' => 'createdevis', 'uses' => 'DevisController@create']);
    Route::get('list', ['as' => 'listdevis', 'uses' => 'DevisController@listdevis']);
    Route::get('/transactions', ['as' => 'list_transactions', 'uses' => 'TransactionsController@list']);
    Route::get('/Items', ['as' => 'listitems', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@list']);
});

?>
```

This is an example of it's been done in laravel so is it possible to acheive that Asp.net core using Minimal APIs.

Thank you for any help

Comment: _"because i don't want to include all the mapping of controllers in program.cs"_ - controllers are usually mapped either with "convention over configuration" principle or mapped via attributes on controllers itself, so idiomatic approach does not require consolidated mapping. Unless you are using Minimal APIs of course.

Comment: I don't want either of them actually i want to keep the controller and proggram.cs clean from annotations and put everything relatable to the request as parameter and method and controllerName and method name also url route in the file that i want to create and then just register that file in program.cs to keep things clean

Comment: There's nothing that prevents you from creating your minimal API over several files. To be honest though, if that's getting too much then you're probably better learning how a "proper" ASP.NET Core API is built rather than trying to replicate the Laravel way. In my experience, trying to fight the conventions I always end up on the losing side. Take this as an opportunity to learn ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @CharguiTaieb you don't need so much code in ASP.NET Core. You don't need to explicitly specify the target for *every* path, although you can. In fact, if you just let ASP.NET Core use controllers and routing, you won't have to specify anything. Just ensure you create Controller files with names and actions that map to conventions, eg `public class TransactionsController { public List<Transaction> Get(){ ... } }`

Comment: The Laravel code you posted shows the use of controllers. Minimal APIs are used when you *don't* want to use separate controllers, hence the name "minimal". If you check the [Minimal API code doc example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-api-code) you'll see there's no need to specify return types or the names of handlers, the minimal API declaration itself includes the handler lambda.  You can put the code in different files if you want but this is really starting to look like Controllers

Comment: You can group endpoints with `MapGroup` which is also included in the doc example.

Comment: @panagio_kanavos Can you provide an example if you don't mind.

Comment: I linked to the documentation example. Are you asking about a Controller example? Right before the Minimal API example is the [API Controllers example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). All this is shown in the docs and tutorials. As phuzi said, you should start learning ASP.NET Core instead of trying to copy what you do in one framework to a completely different one.

Comment: I'm already Learning Asp.Net Core and i guess it's not forbidden nor bad to customize your application template for clean code and better fetching in the future and that's why the minimal Api introduce this features

Comment: _"that's why the minimal API introduce this features"_ No it isn't. It was added as a easy/lightweight entry point to ASP.NET Core for small applications and new developers which doesn't require all the boiler plate code that the more traditional "API controllers and convention over configuration" uses.

Comment: From [Tutorial: Create a minimal API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) - _"Minimal APIs are architected to create HTTP APIs with minimal dependencies. They are ideal for microservices and apps that want to include **only the minimum files, features, and dependencies** in ASP.NET Core."_  [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to achieve that Asp.net core using Minimal APIs.

The calls like `app.MapGet(...)` used to setup the routes with handlers are just method calls. You can move them to static method in any class and just call. For example (another approach can be making a [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) `Program` class and moving such method(s) to separate file(s)):

```
public static class RoutesMap
{
    public static void MapRoutes(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var userEndpoints = app.MapGroup("/user")
            .WithTags("user");
        userEndpoints.MapGet("/items", ...);
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then in the program file you will just call `app.MapRoutes();`.

Also you can introduce several such methods.

If you are using MVC with controllers you can try using the [explicit `MapControllerRoute` calls per controller/controller+action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#multiple-conventional-routes)

P.S.

> to keep things clean

What is considered "clean" is quite opinionated and I would argue that you should try to stick to idiomatic approaches for the tech stack used.

See also:

- [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
- [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
- [Route Handlers in Minimal API apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try that asap along with this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-8.0#endpoint-defined-outside-of-programcs.

Beside i thought that would be much cleaner and readable if the application get bigger in the future

Comment: @CharguiTaieb see also - https://stackoverflow.com/q/70139392/2501279 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75932445/2501279